# How to create an class object to access function from an other class

Tags: c#, wpf

**EDIT 2:** To just clarify what I want to do I´ve created a small sample project. Here´s the MainWindow.

```
    <Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Grid Background="#FF937BFF">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Name="Show_Page1"
                    Content="Page1" 
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Margin="10 5" Click="Show_Page1_Click">
            </Button>
            <Button Name="Show_Page2"
                    Content="Page2" 
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                    Margin="10 5"
                    Grid.Column="1" Click="Show_Page2_Click">
            </Button>
        </Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Frame Height="290" 
                   Name="MainFrame"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
            <Frame Height="290" 
                   Name="SecondFrame"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And the c# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainFrame.Content = new Page1();
        SecondFrame.Content = new Page_Other();
    }

    private void Show_Page1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainFrame.Content = new Page1();
    }

    private void Show_Page2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainFrame.Content = new Page2();
    }
}
```

Both, Page1 and Page2 have the same look.It´s just a button to change a TextBlock´s content. Here is my problem. The TextBlock itself is on an other Page called Page_Other while the button to trigger this action is on Page1 and Page2.

Since I don´t want this post to get even longer here at the end is just the Page1.cs as an example:

```
        public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BTN_Change_TxtBlock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Access function to - or directly change text inside TextBlock "Name:Txt_To_Change" on "Page_Other"
    }
```

Comment: Which class has the function that you want? Could you post its source code?

Comment: Use MVVM approach, and let the view models of the concerned pages share and/or exchange data...

Comment: I´ve added the other class. @elgonzo Sorry I´m pretty new (to C#) so I actually don´t know what MVVM is.

Comment: Does `Core_Layout` create an instance of `Home_Content`? Do you understand that if you have one existing instance, of a class, which you already created and used, which already exists, you can't call a method on that old existing instance by creating a new different instance which is not the same object? You have to get the old instance and use that instead.

Comment: You can check this page. http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation

Comment: @Ed That seems legit. Do you know how to get the old instance?

Comment: Not without seeing the code. You created it somewhere. How do you expect me to know where, or what you did? It's your code, not mine.

Comment: So what do you need from me to be able to do so? The two pages the magic ist all about are already inside the question.

Comment: It sounded like you have a `Core_Layout` that the user can see. It's visible in the UI. You want to call a method on it, so you create a different instance of `Core_Layout`. Am I on the right track? Is it bigger than a breadbox?

Comment: Yes the Core_Layout is basically just a Page with a big Frame + some information on the right side that should always be visible. Inside the Frame Home_Content gets loaded in. Once the user clicks on a Label inside Home_Content, the Frame inside Core_Layout should load up an other page (called Spectate), that replaces Home_Content.

Comment: @Tom OK, so you created a `Core_Layout` somewhere, in some class. Where? What class? Which class creates the pages? Where? Code only. Nothing but code. The moment you describe anything instead of showing me the code for it, I stop helping you. You want to get from an address in Cleveland to an address in Cincinatti. OK, I need three things: 1. The address in Cleveland; 2. The address in Cincinatti; 3. A map that shows the relationship between the two. I don't care if your mother in law lives in Sheboygan, Wisconsin. I don't need to hear any stories about her.

Comment: Since I don´t really understand what else is needed it may help you to have a look at this Picture https://www.pic-upload.de/view-33244678/Classes.png.html of my files.

Comment: Look, the one thing that I made absolutely, unambiguously clear was that I wanted to see code. Maybe you're not sure precisely which code, but you can't possibly have missed the fact that the only thing I want from you is code. Your instinctive response to this is to give me the one thing you can think of that *isn't code*. I don't get it. I really don't. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want multiple classes to talk you will need another class that manages this behavior. (I mean you could tightly couple them but that is bad for so many reasons.)

What many programs do is implement a queue. You create a class that is static or a Singleton pattern so every class can access it. Then you make that class an Observer pattern so classes can subscribe and unsub from various events. This way you can publish an event from a class without knowing exactly what will pick up that event and run with it. This allows you flexibility as you can easily swap classes in and out without causing an issue.

Here is one example of a MessageQueue as a Singleton:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using log4net;

    namespace MyApp
    {
        public interface IMessageQueue
        {
            void Subscribe(string topic, IMessageSubscriber subscriber);
            void UnSubscribe(string topic, IMessageSubscriber subscriber);
            void Notify(string topic, Dictionary<string, string> fields);
            bool AnyoneInterested(string topic);
        }

        public class MessageQueue : IMessageQueue
        {
            private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

            private readonly Dictionary<string, List<IMessageSubscriber>> subscriptions =
                new Dictionary<string, List<IMessageSubscriber>>();

            private static MessageQueue instance;

            private MessageQueue()
            {
            }

            public static MessageQueue GetInstance()
            {
                return instance ?? (instance = new MessageQueue());
            }

            public void Subscribe(string topic, IMessageSubscriber subscriber)
            {
                lock (subscriptions)
                {
                    if (subscriptions.ContainsKey(topic))
                    {
                        subscriptions[topic].Add(subscriber);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        subscriptions.Add(topic, new List<IMessageSubscriber> {subscriber});
                    }
                }
            }

            public void UnSubscribe(string topic, IMessageSubscriber subscriber)
            {
                lock (subscriptions)
                {
                    if (subscriptions != null && !subscriptions.ContainsKey(topic)) return;

                    subscriptions[topic].Remove(subscriber);
                }
            }

            public void Notify(string topic, Dictionary<string, string> fields)
            {
                lock (subscriptions)
                {
                    if (!subscriptions.ContainsKey(topic)) return;

                    log.Info($"Message: {topic}");

                    foreach (var sub in subscriptions[topic])
                    {
                        Task.Run(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                sub.Notify(topic, fields);
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                //supress, should only get here if someone disposed a subscriber without calling unsubscribe
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            public bool AnyoneInterested(string topic)
            {
                lock (subscriptions)
                {
                    return subscriptions.ContainsKey(topic);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And the IMessageSubscriber:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApp
{
    public interface IMessageSubscriber
    {
        void Notify(string topic, Dictionary<string, string> fields);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but since I am pretty new to C# I am not really able to follow you up. I´ve updated my hole post to clarify my problem. Maybe you can help me based on that?  Thanks